get OSError when executing `matplotlib.pyplot.pause(0.2)` at interactive mode
I am try to use matplotlib.pyplot at interactive to draw real time figure. The program is pretty simple:
cat draw.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import random


def get_upper_bound() -> int:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return 30 + random.randint(-3, +3)


def get_lower_bound() -> int:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return -30 + random.randint(-3, +3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
    ax.set_ylim(-50, +50)

    ub = [0 for _ in range(100)]
    lb = [0 for _ in range(100)]
    t = list(range(100)) 

    for i in range(300):
        ub = ub[1:100] + [get_upper_bound()]
        lb = lb[1:100] + [get_lower_bound()]

        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(t, ub)
        ax.plot(t, lb)
        plt.pause(0.2)

By running ipython draw.py, I get a window of figure, it works fine for around 1 seconds, but after that the program crashes:

The error message is:

Installed qt5 event loop hook.
Shell is already running a gui event loop for qt5. Call with no arguments to disable the current loop.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File D:\Users\YLW20\Desktop\draw\draw.py:34
     32 ax.plot(t, ub)
     33 ax.plot(t, lb)
---> 34 plt.pause(0.2)

File D:\packages\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:582, in pause(interval)
    580         canvas.draw_idle()
    581     show(block=False)
--> 582     canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
    583 else:
    584     time.sleep(interval)

File D:\packages\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py:422, in FigureCanvasQT.start_event_loop(self, timeout)
    419     _ = QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(int(timeout * 1000), event_loop.quit)
    421 with _maybe_allow_interrupt(event_loop):
--> 422     qt_compat._exec(event_loop)

File D:\packages\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\contextlib.py:126, in _GeneratorContextManager.__exit__(self, typ, value, traceback)
    124 if typ is None:
    125     try:
--> 126         next(self.gen)
    127     except StopIteration:
    128         return False

File D:\packages\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py:242, in _maybe_allow_interrupt(qapp)
    240 rsock.close()
    241 sn.setEnabled(False)
--> 242 signal.set_wakeup_fd(old_wakeup_fd)
    243 signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, old_sigint_handler)
    244 if handler_args is not None:

OSError: [WinError 6] 句柄无效。

If i run it directly by python draw.py, seems it works okay. But my computer gets pretty lag, and the figure window keeps to eat many of my keyboard event.
I am using:
system Windows 11 23H2
python 3.9.18
ipython 8.12.2
matplotlib 3.7.3
I wonder is there anything wrong with the code, or it is due to the environment.

When I shift to python 3.9.1, python draw.py works pretty well.
